# Office 2011 unable to display image

Tags: microsoft-word-2011, microsoft-office-2011, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I am working in an office using Macs running Office 2011.  One of our colleague's found out today that when opening a pptx file, it had a red X instead of the embedded images, just like; [RED X instead of graphics](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00064_RED_X_instead_of_graphics.htm).

Perhaps my Google fu is not good enough.  We have tried the following and just can't get any file to show images, .docx nor .pptx:

- Reinstall Office.
- Reset compatbitily settings.
- Uninstall Office using AppCleaner and then reinstalling it again.
- Rebooted computer.
- Copy Word/Pointpoint folders to local desktop and open the file locally.

We also tried to open a new PowerPoint document and insert a JPG image to it, that does not work neither:

[image]

There is at least 1 GB of free memory available according to Activity Monitor, and the Mac has a graphics card. Any ideas?

Comment: The JPG file you are inserting to the new powerpoint document may be corrupt.  Can you try the same procedure with a different JPG?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that Office is looking for an image file. Probably the images in the Powerpoint (or whichever Office document) were **linked** to the original images files (instead of being **inserted** or **embedded**) in the Powerpoint file (see explanation here: http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/picturesandvisuals/insert-and-link-picture-ppt2010.html). See if the original creator of the Powerpoint is willing to re-insert those images (and embed them and not link them), save it and resend it. As you can read from the error, user `mariai` has the original images ;-)

Comment: @Kent yes, we tried a few different JPG, they are all just ordinary photos and wallpapers that works in Preview, and works in Office as long as it is on all other Macs in the office, so there are something wrong with this instance of Office that we have no ideas how to fix.

Comment: @agtoever yes this is the user mariai's computer, but we are not even trying to open a powerpoint that's linking to images at this stage, the above error is when we try to create a brand new powerpoint on the local desktop and insert an image from the local drive. I think doing it this way we have eliminate the possibility of images being linked on a remote location, but it still doesn't work and we are stuck.

Comment: I would create a new temporary user, and try to do the same thing in Powerpoint.  If it works, then there is likely an issue with user marial's Office 2011 preferences.

Comment: I think there are images in the Powerpoint template (which is opened by default when starting Powerpoint). Delete or replace the file: 'C:\Users\maraia\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Blank.potx'

Comment: Thanks everyone. Office 2011 works now that the computer has been upgraded to Mavericks. ~_~

Comment: I've never had this problem before but after Sierra install, the same problem here... I've tried to reinstall/upgrade/downgrade Office 2011 without success. If I open the file on a Windows machine, it works great, but on my mac on Sierra, the pictures doesn't show at all (but I don't have a red cross).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 2011 works now that the computer in question has been upgraded to Mavericks. ~_~

This is probably not "the answer", and I suggest you to read and try all the links and suggestions in my initial question and comments to it.